# Play framework - No Writeable for File

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a method `func(): Future[Option[File]]` in a service I created, that creates a CSV file.
I want to write an API request (with controller), that return that file.

The method I wrote in my controller:

```scala
def APIFunction(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
  (for {
    res <- Future.successful(Ok(service.func()))
  } yield res)
    .recover({ case ex =>
      logger.error("A problem occurred.", ex)
      BadRequest(s"A problem detected: $ex")
    })
}
```

The problem is that to use func I need to implicitly inject `Writeable[Future[Option[File]]]`.

The problem I get:

> Could not find a suitable constructor in play.api.http.Writeable. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
> at play.api.http.Writeable.class(Writeable.scala:24)

I'm new to Scala, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Antoine's response below is a good one. Note that if `service.func()` returns a `Future[T]`, you need to `map` over it like `service.func().map(t => Ok(t))` to obtain a `Future[Result]` rather than doing `Future.successful(Ok(service.func()))` which gives you a `Future[Result[Future[T]]]`.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the basics of Scala and Futures if you are new to it

Answer (score 2):

What you need is actually [`Ok.sendFile`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaStream).

Using this, you can solve your problem as such:

```scala
def APIFunction(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    (for {
      maybeFile <- service.func()
      result = maybeFile match {
        case Some(file) => Ok.sendFile(file)
        case None => BadRequest("whatever")
      }
    } yield result)
      .recover { case ex =>
        logger.error("A problem occurred.", ex)
        BadRequest(s"A problem detected: $ex")
      } 
  }
```

(I'm writing this without testing)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. This didn't solve the problem of: Could not find a suitable constructor in play.api.http.Writeable.